# I can't move any controls in designer

Tags: windows-forms-designer

All my controls are now in the lower panel of the designer and I can't move them or select them in the upper panel.
What did I do and how do I put it back to normal?

[screetshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AtxB.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

So apparently, there is a difference between unused references and unneeded ones. I caused the problem by removing all unused references not thinking that they may  be unused but still necessary.
It cost me 6 hours to invent lots of new curse words and learn one lesson.

Thank you anyway